# C# data table division

Tags: c#

I have a data table which I am wring out to csv.
How do I divide two cells **row.Cells[BuyNom.Index]** and **row.Cells[SellNom.Index]** to obtain a value in the 'Price" row?

fxRow["NetAmount"] = row.Cells[Amount.Index].Value.ToString();

fxRow["Price"] =

Thanks

Full code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridRFX.Rows)
 {
 if (row.Index == gridRBCFX.NewRowIndex || row.Cells[Pfolio.Index].Value == null)
       continue;                         
        DataRow fxRow = ezefxTable.NewRow();
         fxRow["SettleCcy"] = row.Cells[Buy.Index].Value.ToString();
         fxRow["Account"] = "RBC";
         fxRow["Fund"] = row.Cells[Pfolio.Index].Value.ToString();
         fxRow["Strategy"] = "Long";
         fxRow["Trader"] = "Trader1";
         fxRow["Counterparty"] = "Notional";
         fxRow["TransType"] = "Purchase";
         fxRow["NetAmount"] = row.Cells[BuyNom.Index].Value.ToString();
         fxRow["Price"] = 
         fxRow["Currency"] = row.Cells[Sell.Index].Value.ToString();
         fxRow["TradeDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[TradeDateRBC.Index].Value.ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
         ezefxTable.Rows.Add(fxRow);                                    

    }
     gridFX.DataSource = fxTable;
```

Comment: can we see code ? it's not really clear what are u asking for !?

Comment: Hi - see above. I need to update the "Price" row by dividing row.Cells[BuyNom.Index] with row.Cells[SellNom.Index]

Comment: for every row in table ?

Comment: Yes, for fxRow["Price"] =  only though. thanks

Comment: `fxRow["Price"] = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[BuyNom.Index])\Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[SellNom.Index])`

Comment: many thanks for your help?